# Displaying the output of a cell in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a cell of the of the following :

displayop =

```
[2114x1 datetime]    [2114x1 double]    [2114x1 double]    {2114x1 cell}
```

How I can see the output of displayop ? I have tried using cell2mat, but gives me the following error: All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type.

I am looking at the below output for displayop:

03/11/2016 7544 7544 'UP'

Comment: `disp(displayop{i})` for valid values of `i`

Comment: @Amro : There are four columns, so replacing i with 1 to 4, will only display the columns individually. I wanted to display all four column values together

Comment: ok, how about using a table: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-table.html. Does your MATLAB version support it? (i think they were added in R2013b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using MATLAB's tables:

```
% a sample cell array resembling your data
>> displayop = {datetime(2016,3,(1:10)') (1:10)' rand(10,1) cellstr(num2str((11:20)'))}
displayop = 
    [10x1 datetime]    [10x1 double]    [10x1 double]    {10x1 cell}
```

Now:

```
% convert to table, which is displayed nicely
>> table(displayop{:}, 'VariableNames',{'dt','x','y','str'})
ans = 
        dt         x        y        str 
    ___________    __    ________    ____
    01-Mar-2016     1    0.049654    '11'
    02-Mar-2016     2     0.90272    '12'
    03-Mar-2016     3     0.94479    '13'
    04-Mar-2016     4     0.49086    '14'
    05-Mar-2016     5     0.48925    '15'
    06-Mar-2016     6     0.33772    '16'
    07-Mar-2016     7     0.90005    '17'
    08-Mar-2016     8     0.36925    '18'
    09-Mar-2016     9      0.1112    '19'
    10-Mar-2016    10     0.78025    '20'
```

#### Bonus:

You can still use plain old cell-arrays:

```
>> C = [num2cell(displayop{1}) num2cell(displayop{2}) num2cell(displayop{3}) displayop{4}]
C = 
    [01-Mar-2016]    [ 1]    [0.0497]    '11'
    [02-Mar-2016]    [ 2]    [0.9027]    '12'
    [03-Mar-2016]    [ 3]    [0.9448]    '13'
    [04-Mar-2016]    [ 4]    [0.4909]    '14'
    [05-Mar-2016]    [ 5]    [0.4893]    '15'
    [06-Mar-2016]    [ 6]    [0.3377]    '16'
    [07-Mar-2016]    [ 7]    [0.9001]    '17'
    [08-Mar-2016]    [ 8]    [0.3692]    '18'
    [09-Mar-2016]    [ 9]    [0.1112]    '19'
    [10-Mar-2016]    [10]    [0.7803]    '20'
```

Comment: Thanks for the bonus too !